# $\mu(X)=\infty$, and $f\in L^p (X)$ for some $1<p<\infty \Longrightarrow f\in L^1 (X)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

What are some interesting examples of a measure space $(X,\mu)$ such that $\mu(X)=\infty$ and

> $f\in L^p (X)$ for some $1<p<\infty \Longrightarrow f\in L^1 (X)$

All the examples I have found are some what trivial, such as the point space $\left\{*\right\}$.

What I know is that, if the measure is $\sigma$-finite, there exists $f\notin L^1 (X)$ such that for all $1<p\leq\infty$, $f\in L^p (X)$. This means that no $\sigma$-finite examples exist...

Please enlighten me.

Comment: If $f \in L^p$, then $\{ x : f(x) \neq 0\}$ has $\sigma$-finite measure. So in a way, no interesting examples exist.